# In DB table, How to update query after select query?

Tags: mysql

I want update query after select query.

first SELECT query , `SELECT * from be_settings order by seq desc limit 1`

this select query  is based on seq, retrieve the last inserted record.

I want update on this record.

second Update Query, `UPDATE be_settings set appgubun ='CCTV', running ='on'`.

how to update query after select query?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via an update with a subquery:

```
UPDATE be_settings
SET appgubun = 'CCTV', running = 'on'
WHERE seq = (SELECT t.max_seq FROM (SELECT MAX(seq) AS max_seq FROM be_settings) t );
```

The subquery in the `WHERE` clause is necessary because it involves the `be_settings` table, which is the target of the update.  The following would give an error:

```
WHERE seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) FROM be_settings)
```

Comment: thanks, but `Unknown column 't.seq' in 'field list'` this message.

Comment: @hyunwookcho Sorry, I forgot an alias.  It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
UPDATE be_settings set appgubun ='CCTV', running ='on' where  seq= '4'
```

Assuming your there is `seq` column on `be_settings` and it is primary key.

and 4 is the last inserted id you are getting from `select query`.

if you are getting that seq in any variable based on programming language then you have to use that particular variable.

**You have to this if you do not want to use subquery.**